# Passing an Activity and Modifying its views

Tags: android, oop

I have an activity class A which has a few TextViews as its member variables. Class A has getter methods for the three TextViews. Can I pass a reference of A to Class B and modify the three TextViews? Is this good programming practice?

Edit: Code -

Class A

```
public class A extends Activity {

    private TextView tv1;
    private TextView tv2;
    private TextView tv3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // initialize tv1, tv2, tv3 here

        // Pass a referce of A to B.
        new B(this);
    }

    public TextView getTv1() {
        return tv1;
    }

    public TextView getTv2() {
        return tv2;
    }

    public TextView getTv3() {
        return tv3;
    }
}
```

Class B -

```
public class B {
    public B(A a){
        a.getTv1().setText("Is");
        a.getTv2().setText("this");
        a.getTv3().setText("correct?");
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a best practice. Instead you can pass values from A to B by using `Intent`.

Comment: I guess it can't be passed from A to B via intent because B is not an activity. Or may be if we pass context of that activity in B.

Answer (score 0):

You can, you only have to make sure that anything you're doing to your `Views` you do on the main thread. From some other thread you may use `runOnUiThread`.

You also can use a `Handler`. You define a `Handler` in an `Activity` and post messages to that handler from wherever you want. They will be then processed on the main thread.

It probably only makes sense when your Activity is visible and another class is running some thread so your Views get updated while they are visible. Otherwise if Activity is not visible you can just set your views in `onResume` or `onStart`

Still to avoid too many dependencies using a `Handler` seems to be fine in this case.

**Edit**: In the code you posted why do you need `B` at all?

Comment: This is just sample code. In my actual code, class A is really long (over 1000 LOC). This is because of a private WebViewClient class (~200 lines) which tries to modify most of the member variables. I wanted to make it a separate public class for better readability.